# Tensorflow Check failed: work_element_count > 0 (0 vs -2147483648)

Tags: tensorflow

I trained the semantic segmentation model using functional API and after the training is done I loaded the best weight and ran the prediction.

Then this issue was raised and I'm not sure where to fix this bug.

```
F ./tensorflow/core/util/gpu_launch_config.h:129] Check failed: work_element_count > 0 (0 vs. -2147483648)
```

my code is like

```
    input_shape = (512,512,3)
    Input_layer = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    
    model_Unet_input = model_Unet(Input_layer)
    model_deeplabv3plus_input = model_DeeplabV3Plus(Input_layer)
    
    modela_output = model_Unet.layers[-3].output
    model_deeplabV3Plus_previous= model_DeeplabV3Plus.layers[-2].output
    model_deeplabV3Plus_output = layers.Conv2D(16,3,padding='same')(model_deeplabV3Plus_previous)
    
    concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([modela_output,model_deeplabV3Plus_output], axis=3)
    data_output = layers.Conv2D(2, 3, padding='same',activation = "sigmoid")(concat)
    
    model_UNet_DeeplabV3Plus_concat= Model([model_Unet.input, model_DeeplabV3Plus.input],data_output)
    model_UNet_DeeplabV3Plus_concat.summary()
        
    model_UNet_DeeplabV3Plus_concat.fit([x_train_processed_res,x_train_processed_res],
    y_train,verbose=1,batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs, validation_split=0.2,
    callbacks =[model_UNet_DeeplabV3Plus_concat_checkpoint])
    model_Unet_deeplab_checkpointlist = os.listdir(model_UNet_DeeplabV3Plus_concat_dir+'/ckpt')
        


    model_UNet_DeeplabV3Plus_concat.load_weights(model_UNet_DeeplabV3Plus_concat_dir+'/ckpt/'+model_Unet_deeplab_checkpointlist[-1])
                    y_pred_Unet_deeplab=model_UNet_DeeplabV3Plus_concat.predict([x_test_processed_res,x_test_processed_res])

y_pred_Unet_deeplab_argmax=np.argmax(y_pred_Unet_deeplab, axis=3)
```

my environment is
python 3.9
Tensorflow 2.8.1
keras 2.8.1
cuda version 11.6
cudnn 11.4

can sombody help me ?

model summary is below

```
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
 data (InputLayer)              [(None, 512, 512, 3  0           []
                                )]

 bn_data (BatchNormalization)   (None, 512, 512, 3)  9           ['data[0][0]']

 zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 518, 518, 3)  0          ['bn_data[0][0]']

 conv0 (Conv2D)                 (None, 256, 256, 64  9408        ['zero_padding2d[0][0]']
                                )

 bn0 (BatchNormalization)       (None, 256, 256, 64  256         ['conv0[0][0]']
                                )

 relu0 (Activation)             (None, 256, 256, 64  0           ['bn0[0][0]']
                                )

 zero_padding2d_1 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 258, 258, 64  0          ['relu0[0][0]']
 D)                             )

 pooling0 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 128, 128, 64  0           ['zero_padding2d_1[0][0]']
                                )

 stage1_unit1_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 128, 128, 64  256        ['pooling0[0][0]']
 zation)                        )

 stage1_unit1_relu1 (Activation  (None, 128, 128, 64  0          ['stage1_unit1_bn1[0][0]']
 )                              )

 stage1_unit1_conv1 (Conv2D)    (None, 128, 128, 64  4096        ['stage1_unit1_relu1[0][0]']
                                )

 stage1_unit1_bn2 (BatchNormali  (None, 128, 128, 64  256        ['stage1_unit1_conv1[0][0]']
 zation)                        )

 stage1_unit1_relu2 (Activation  (None, 128, 128, 64  0          ['stage1_unit1_bn2[0][0]']
 )                              )

 zero_padding2d_2 (ZeroPadding2  (None, 130, 130, 64  0          ['stage1_unit1_relu2[0][0]']
 D)                             )

 stage1_unit1_conv2 (Conv2D)    (None, 128, 128, 64  36864       ['zero_padding2d_2[0][0]']
                                )

 stage1_unit1_bn3 (BatchNormali  (None, 128, 128, 64  256        ['stage1_unit1_conv2[0][0]']
 zation)                        )

 stage1_unit1_relu3 (Activation  (None, 128, 128, 64  0          ['stage1_unit1_bn3[0][0]']
 )                              )

 stage1_unit1_conv3 (Conv2D)    (None, 128, 128, 25  16384       ['stage1_unit1_relu3[0][0]']
                                6)

 stage1_unit1_sc (Conv2D)       (None, 128, 128, 25  16384       ['stage1_unit1_relu1[0][0]']
                                6)

 add (Add)                      (None, 128, 128, 25  0           ['stage1_unit1_conv3[0][0]',
                                6)                                'stage1_unit1_sc[0][0]']

 stage1_unit2_bn1 (BatchNormali  (None, 128, 128, 25  1024       ['add[0][0]']
 zation)                        6)

 stage1_unit2_relu1 (Activation  (None, 128, 128, 25  0          ['stage1_unit2_bn1[0][0]']
 )                              6)

**........ (middle ) ..............**

 decoder_stage3a_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 256, 256, 32  128        ['decoder_stage3a_conv[0][0]']
 lization)                      )

 batch_normalization_5 (BatchNo  (None, 32, 32, 256)  1024       ['conv2d_5[0][0]']
 rmalization)

 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 48  3072        ['conv2_block3_2_relu[0][0]']
                                )

 decoder_stage3a_relu (Activati  (None, 256, 256, 32  0          ['decoder_stage3a_bn[0][0]']
 on)                            )

 tf.nn.relu_5 (TFOpLambda)      (None, 32, 32, 256)  0           ['batch_normalization_5[0][0]']

 batch_normalization_6 (BatchNo  (None, 128, 128, 48  192        ['conv2d_6[0][0]']
 rmalization)                   )

 decoder_stage3b_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 256, 256, 32  9216        ['decoder_stage3a_relu[0][0]']
                                )

 up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 25  0          ['tf.nn.relu_5[0][0]']
                                6)

 tf.nn.relu_6 (TFOpLambda)      (None, 128, 128, 48  0           ['batch_normalization_6[0][0]']
                                )

 decoder_stage3b_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 256, 256, 32  128        ['decoder_stage3b_conv[0][0]']
 lization)                      )

 concatenate_1 (Concatenate)    (None, 128, 128, 30  0           ['up_sampling2d_1[0][0]',
                                4)                                'tf.nn.relu_6[0][0]']

 decoder_stage3b_relu (Activati  (None, 256, 256, 32  0          ['decoder_stage3b_bn[0][0]']
 on)                            )

 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 25  700416      ['concatenate_1[0][0]']
                                6)

 decoder_stage4_upsampling (UpS  (None, 512, 512, 32  0          ['decoder_stage3b_relu[0][0]']
 ampling2D)                     )

 batch_normalization_7 (BatchNo  (None, 128, 128, 25  1024       ['conv2d_7[0][0]']
 rmalization)                   6)

 decoder_stage4a_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 512, 512, 16  4608        ['decoder_stage4_upsampling[0][0]
                                )                                ']

 tf.nn.relu_7 (TFOpLambda)      (None, 128, 128, 25  0           ['batch_normalization_7[0][0]']
                                6)

 decoder_stage4a_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 512, 512, 16  64         ['decoder_stage4a_conv[0][0]']
 lization)                      )
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 25  589824      ['tf.nn.relu_7[0][0]']
                                6)
 decoder_stage4a_relu (Activati  (None, 512, 512, 16  0          ['decoder_stage4a_bn[0][0]']
 on)                            )
 batch_normalization_8 (BatchNo  (None, 128, 128, 25  1024       ['conv2d_8[0][0]']
 rmalization)                   6)

 decoder_stage4b_conv (Conv2D)  (None, 512, 512, 16  2304        ['decoder_stage4a_relu[0][0]']
                                )
 tf.nn.relu_8 (TFOpLambda)      (None, 128, 128, 25  0           ['batch_normalization_8[0][0]']
                                6)
 decoder_stage4b_bn (BatchNorma  (None, 512, 512, 16  64         ['decoder_stage4b_conv[0][0]']
 lization)                      )
 up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 512, 512, 25  0          ['tf.nn.relu_8[0][0]']
                                6)
 decoder_stage4b_relu (Activati  (None, 512, 512, 16  0          ['decoder_stage4b_bn[0][0]']
 on)                            )
 conv2d_10 (Conv2D)             (None, 512, 512, 16  36880       ['up_sampling2d_2[0][0]']
                                )
 concatenate_2 (Concatenate)    (None, 512, 512, 32  0           ['decoder_stage4b_relu[0][0]',
                                )                                 'conv2d_10[0][0]']
 conv2d_11 (Conv2D)             (None, 512, 512, 2)  578         ['concatenate_2[0][0]']

==================================================================================================
Total params: 44,450,523
Trainable params: 44,370,229
Non-trainable params: 80,294
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Include the model summary in your question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks for quick comment. I added the model summary actaully it was too long to add so i cut the middle part of it. the body did not allow me to add more than 30k characters. basically what I'm trying to do is using functional API I'm combining Unet and deeplabV3+ taking 2 same image inputs and producing 1 output with concatenated layer. Could you help me with this issue?

Comment: I have been looking for solutions everywhere but have been struggling for a few days.  I really appreciate your help. the training is no issue and I can save the weights too. I think this issue occurs when I load the best weights saved to the same model architecture and try to predict the test images. when I load the weight on google colab it does work without issue for prediction. google colab is just not suitable to predict the amount of test data I want to run.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue (except that I got it on [line 160](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/16d4106ffaa71b02ba5d5b4961eef07e46ea4f0b/tensorflow/core/util/gpu_launch_config.h#L160) and not on [line 129](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/16d4106ffaa71b02ba5d5b4961eef07e46ea4f0b/tensorflow/core/util/gpu_launch_config.h#L129), but it is on the same function `CHECK_GT`. The issue comes from the function `GetGpuLaunchConfig` with an Int32 `work_element_count` parameter. Somehow, the value passed to the function is bigger than the maximum value of Int32 (2 147 483 647)

Comment: Therefore, when casting such a big value to an Int32, it is "wrapped" to the min value of Int32, explaining why we got such a big negative value. I have no idea how to fix the bug, apart from modifying the `int` parameter to a `long` and rebuilding tensorflow. Maybe reducing model and/or data size could also help. I let [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15698) as a reference